# Build VC++ projects created with Visual Studio 2012 without Visual Studio being installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-c++-2012

If I have a Visual Studio Solution file of VS2012 with few C++ projects, can I build this solution without installing Visual Studio 2012 (any edition) itself? I do not want to install the Visual Studio 2012 Express either. We are setting up our build environment on a Windows 10 machine.

If it is possible, please let us know what are the prerequisites that needs to be installed/copied on build machine and the steps to build our solution.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: VS2012: I doubt it. But if you really don't want the IDE then you could go with https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/announcing-the-official-release-of-the-visual-c-build-tools-2015/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @stijn !! I have a question here - Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 requires .Net framework 4.5.1 installed. However, our projects are built using .Net 4.0. So will it work in our case?

Comment: No idea, but you could build your projects using .Net 4.5?